# How to hide the new download button from st.dataframe - Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

The new version of streamlit when using st.dataframe shows an icon to download the data, I dont waht to have that option sometimes, how do I prevent that ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should add `CSS` with `{display:none}` to this button . If you need to change it when you press button then it may need to use `JavaScript`